# Comparing elements of lists and calculate frequency of resulting values

Tags: python, list, numpy

Lets say, i have a list of floats, that are very similiar, i.e.

```
alpha = [11.2876,11.2895,1.9746]
```

Two elements of them are equal up to `np.round(x,2)`. How do I get the information out of this list, that two elements have the same value, that is `np.round(x,2)`, namely *11.28* and one has the value *1.9746*.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure of what output you're expecting, but one idea could be to use sets?

```
set([round(i, 2) for i in alpha])
# {1.97, 11.29}
```

Or perhaps a `Counter`?

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(round(i, 2) for i in alpha)
# Counter({11.29: 2, 1.97: 1})
```

If you actually want to `floor` to the second decimal:

```
import math
Counter(math.floor(i * 100)/100.0 for i in alpha)
# Counter({11.28: 2, 1.97: 1})
```

Comment: But then you are missing the information that there were initially two elements of the same value, which OP seemed to be interested in. Edit: The counter solution does retain the information.

Comment: Yes then a COunter is better for that purpose @tom

Answer (score 3):

You could just convert it and check like,

```
>>> alpha = [11.2876,11.2895,1.9746]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(np.round(x,2) for x in alpha)
>>> c
Counter({11.29: 2, 1.97: 1})
>>> next(k for k,v in c.items() if v == 2)
11.29
```

But if there is not value by the count you are look for, then it may raise `StopIteration`.

```
>>> next(k for k,v in c.items() if v == 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

And if you don't want it to raise a `StopIteration` if it cannot find any value by that count then,

```
>>> k = next((k for k,v in c.items() if v == 3), None)
>>> k
>>> if k is None:
...   print('Not found')
... 
Not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a matrix/dictionary indexed by the entries of your array and valued by `True` or `False` depending on their absolute distance.

The code to do that would be

```
equal_mtx = {}
for i in range(len(alpha)):
    for j in range(len(alpha)):
        equal_mtx[(alpha[i],alpha[j])] = equal_mtx.get((alpha[j],alpha[i]), (np.round(np.abs(alpha[i]-alpha[j]), 2)) == 0)
```

And the outcome for `equal_mtx' is

```
{(11.2876, 11.2876): True,
 (11.2876, 11.2895): True,
 (11.2876, 1.9746): False,
 (11.2895, 11.2876): True,
 (11.2895, 11.2895): True,
 (11.2895, 1.9746): False,
 (1.9746, 11.2876): False,
 (1.9746, 11.2895): False,
 (1.9746, 1.9746): True}
```